# UIActionSheet With PickerView not showing up in iPad

Tags: ios, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

I am using the following code to add an actionsheet with a picker view on it to my app.  From the iPhone, it displays perfectly, but when viewing on iPad (Universal app), it shows a very small pickerview with none of the other buttons right on the center of the page.

```
UIActionSheet *menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Chapter"
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                        destructiveButtonTitle:@"Select"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
    // Add the picker
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,185,0,0)];

    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;    // note this is default to NO

    [menu addSubview:pickerView];
    [menu showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
    [menu setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 700)];

    [pickerView release];
    [menu release];
```

Comment: Don't misuse a `UIActionSheet` this way. It is not designed to allow for arbitrary views to be added to it. Use some other non-UIActionSheet solution for your needs.

Comment: It works perfectly for the iPhone.

Comment: How did you present the actionsheet ? Is it on a popover ? Which method you are calling for showing the actionsheet ?

Comment: @user717452 That's not the point. `UIActionSheet` has a fixed API for showing a set of choices. That's it. That is all it is supposed to do. You are not supposed to mess with it by adding custom subviews. Odds are pretty good that what is working on the iPhone now won't work in a future iOS update. Use the right tool for any given task.

Comment: @MidhunMP as is written in my original question `[menu showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];`

Comment: @rmaddy  There is nothing wrong with adding subViews to a UIActionSheet.  It has been done for the last 5 years.  Just google UIActionSheet and addSubview and you'll find many examples.

Comment: @user717452 I know it has been done. That doesn't make it correct. Do what you want. You will regret it at some point when UIActionSheet changes in a future update of iOS.

Comment: Figured out the issue no thanks to @rmaddy.  Adding /n/n/n in front of title increases the length of the Action Sheet in iPad allowing for the UIPickerView to be shown.  Seeing as this worked in iOS 3, and still works on iOS 7 Beta, I think it is safe to say that ass UIActionSheets have the method of addSubview: in them, it is completely safe to use in this manner.

Comment: Well it's a few years later and it still works. @rmaddy   You just added /n to fix the problem? I'm doing the exact same thing-it works fine on iPhone but with iPad it doesn't show up. If I move my hand I can hear the clicking and the debugger shows that it's working it just doesn't show